# Strlen() function giving "Segmentation Fault" error

Tags: segmentation-fault, strlen

So this is my code:

```
int c;
char b[c];

scanf("%s",b);
c=strlen(b);

printf("\n");
printf("%s\n",b);
```

When I execute it, it keeps giving me a "Segmentation Fault (core dumped)" error. I don't want to define the string size before hand. I want the program to determine it after I finish writing the string.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
int c;
char b[c];
```

gives you undefined behavior, as `c` is not initialized, but is then used as the array size for `b`.  Undefined behavior means that anything might happen afterwards, including running ok for awhile and then core dumping later.

It sounds like what you want is to determine the string length from the input, but yout can't do that with an array in C, as array sizes are constant, determined when the array is declared.  Instead, you'll need to use a dynamically allocated buffer that you resize as appropriate when you read your string.  If you're using POSIX, you can let the stdio library do  that for you with an `m` modifier on your scanf call:

```
char *b;
if (scanf("%ms", &b) > 0) {
    printf("%s\n", b);
    free(b); }
```

If you're not using POSIX C, you instead need to first allocate a bigger than possibly needed buffer (and optionally later resize it) or not use `scanf` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My program is supposed to: Prompt me to write a string with as many characters as I want, then determine the size of that string, thus updating "b" with it's actual size. I don't want to pre-declare the size, nor establish any kind of limit.